# selectize.js : Preselect more than one value (default tagging values)

Tags: jquery, html, selectize.js

This HTML Code:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" placeholder="Beruf">
<option value="">-- Bitte wählen -- </option>
<option value="1">Koch</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Fischer</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">Schweisser</option>
<option value="4">Lehrer</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">Bauer</option>
</select>
```

Javascript (selectize.js):

```
$('#mySelect').selectize({
    maxItems : 3
});
```

Gives this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

My Question is:
How can I **preselect or preload more than one tag**?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the multiple attribute :

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple name="mySelect" placeholder="Beruf">
  <option value="">-- Bitte wählen -- </option>
  <option value="1">Koch</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Fischer</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">Schweisser</option>
  <option value="4">Lehrer</option>
  <option value="5" selected="selected">Bauer</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/w99f3qf8/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [] to the name of the select and also add multiple tag, like this:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect[]" placeholder="Beruf" multiple>
```

Comment: Easier and optimum solution than using a loop.

Comment: Don't need the name to be [], just multiple attribute